# . net mvc multiple filters only execute one

Tags: c#

I have two custom filters, which are labeled on the controller at the same time, but only one is executed.
`

```
[ModelState]
    [Authentication]
    public class HomeController : Controller
```

`Only the authentication filter is executed, but the ModelState filter is not.`

```
public class ModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            ModelStateDictionary modelState = context.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;
            if (!modelState.IsValid)
            {
                List<string> errors = new List<string>();
                var errorList = modelState.Values
                    .Select(x => x.Errors)
                    .ToList();
                foreach (var error in errorList)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < error.Count; i++)
                    {
                        errors.Add(error[i].ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                context.Result = new FastResult(20011, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errors));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
public class AuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            try
            {
```

`

I want to execute the ModelState filter first and then the Authentication

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `Order` parameter,

```
[ModelState(Order=1)]
[Authentication(Order=2)]
public class HomeController : Controller {
 //code omitted
}
```

See the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionfilterattribute.order?view=aspnetcore-7.0).